# Java: Force subclasses to override methods of the Superclass

Tags: java, methods, overriding, superclass

How can I write a method and force the subclasses to override this method. In Eclipse it should show in the Quick-Fix Dialog: "Add unimplemented methods".

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> ***How can I write a method and force the subclasses to override this method.***

Declare the method as `abstract`:

[image]

Eclipse will give you the "Add unimplemented methods"-option for all (unimplemented) abstract methods and interface methods.

Comment: Not a general answer. A class with an abstract method can't be instantiated. (only it's sub-classes can)

Comment: An abstract class is instantiated when its subclass is instantiated.

Comment: I meant that I have instances of both the base class and subclasses, and both need an actual implementation of a method, but subclasses must be enforced to override the base class implementation.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus, do you mean that you _have_ an implementation in the base class, but still want to require subclasses to implement (override) the method?

Comment: Yes. Although I eventually settled on making a separate base class that isn't polymorphically connected

Answer (score 8):

Just declare the method as [abstract](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) in the base class. All children classes will then be forced to implement it. Alternatively you could also use an [interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) instead of a concrete class, which is simply an agreement that the methods defined will be implemented. Either one is fine, it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by making the  method `abstract` (not providing a default implementation).

Answer (score 3):

Or if you do NOT want your class to be an abstract class, you can throw your own MustOverrideException at the method that you want to force to be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the method as `abstract`.